# gettext() equivalent in Intl library?

Tags: php, gettext, intl

I'm looking for a way to to do i18n and l10n.

I've used `gettext` before and it was good: I would simply create .mo files in different languages and everything that needed to be translated would be in this notation:

```
echo __('string to be translated');
```

I know that there is Intl library built into PHP now, and I've been told that I should use it instead of `gettext()`.

After reading through [everything there is about Intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) on php.net, I see that it has some nice features like locale handling, string comparison, number formatting, etc.

What I can't figure out is how I would handle regular string to string translation using Intl library. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use gettext. Intl (like ICU underneath it) is for l10n, not loading translations.

Comment: see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051104/are-icu-resource-bundles-meant-for-message-translation-resources - I would not agree with this statement. You may choose to use gettext, but ICU underneath is for loading translations.  ( Steven R. Loomis, ICU project )

Comment: I would be interested in how you came to your conclusion. Or perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: I probably didn't realize that "ResourceBundle" was for strings, since "resource" has a wider meaning in my programming experience.

Comment: thanks,, that's a good point. I'm too familiar with 'our' definition ( starting with java.util.ResourceBundle ) .. will try to make sure the docs are clearer.

Answer (score 6):

That advise wasn't very truthful. The intl functions can be used in conjunction to gettext, not as replacement.

[`MessageFormatter`](http://php.net/MessageFormatter) is what people have in mind when they associate INTL with text translations. The examples suggest so. But in reality it's just a `sprintf` on steroids. It injects numbers into existing strings. (I'm not even sure how the locale support is of any use there, as it just serves as internal switch.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I used intl for translations (tested on php v. 5.3.10 and 5.4.7):

### intl.php

```
namespace Example;
class Intl {

  private $resource;

  public function __construct() {
    $bundle_location = "./locales";
    $user_locale = \Locale::acceptFromHttp( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );
    $this->resource = new \ResourceBundle( $user_locale, $bundle_location );
  }

 ...
```

### display.php

```
 use Example\Intl;

 $intl = new Intl();
 $r = $intl->resource;

 echo $r['string_to_be_translated'];

 ...
```

### resource bundles

In the `locales` directory, I have my resource files:

root.res - root language (English)

```
root { 
  string_to_be_translated {String to be translated } 
}
```

ja.res - Japanese

```
ja { 
  string_to_be_translated {\u5909\u63DB\u3055\u308C\u308B\u6587\u5B57\u5217 }
}
```

sp.res - Spanish

```
sp { 
  string_to_be_translated {Cadena a ser traducido }
}
```

(etc)