# Are ICU resource bundles meant for message translation resources

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, icu

I understand the localization part of ICU - date, time and currency formats, collation, etc. When it comes to message translation, I see people stating  that ICU does not provide functionality for message translation - check for example [this SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644412/php-gettext-analog-in-intl-library).

However, when checking ICU docs,  we find that it provides resources bundles, and the documentation does seem to hint to using them for message translation:

In [PHP intl documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.resourcebundle.php) for example:

> Localized software products often require sets of data that are to be
>   customized depending on current locale, e.g.: messages, labels,
>   formatting patterns. ICU resource mechanism allows to define sets of
>   resources that the application can load on locale basis, while
>   accessing them in unified locale-independent fashion.

The documentation here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/resources
describes functionality similar to a key-value store, with text sources that can be compiled into binary format.

My question is whether ICU resource bundles (including the access functionality and the storage format) are meant for - or it is part of their purpose  - to be used for message translation - for example like gettext and .po files are. If such, is there any resources or tutorials that discuss this usage.

Or a rewording: in its design goals, is the ICU meant to be used in conjunction with a separate message translation facility, or does it strive to provide such functionality itself, or is it that both options are possible.

Comment: Basel, It's been said that if the hearer didn't understand, then communication has failed, regardless of the speaker's intention.  With that in mind, I would be interested to know how you came to your conclusion.  The ICU page you linked to shows lots of examples of messages in ICU format, for example: 'optionMessage{"unrecognized command line option:"}' - is there some wording that should be added to make it more clear?

Comment: This is not to discredit - we all know writing docs sucks. The doc is overall wordy. Overview section doesn't give any idea about subject - acid test: if overview is taken out and read separately, does it explain basic concepts. The author delves into detail without first stating where detail fits in the big picture - an off-putting style. On examples - there is one and it's in the XLIFF section. Makes reader wonder if this is something related to using XLIFF with the tool. Overall, the reader has to do a lot of thinking trying to understand what's meant. A book to check: 'Don't make think'.

Comment: thank you for the constructive criticism and suggestion of http://amzn.to/12h3N

Comment: I added a Wikipedia-like 'see also' link to http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/localizing after the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes ICU resource bundles are meant to be used for the purpose of retrieving messages.  The answer to the other SOF question is incorrect as regards ICU.  The link you provided is correct, and also mentions converting ICU resource bundle formats in and out of XLIFF.  ICU also provides a `catgets()` style wrapper in http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucat_8h.html

ICU wouldn't prevent you from using a separate message retrieval facility, but it is certainly meant to be one- and is used that way.

-Steven, ICU project

*Edit* ICU does not currently/officially have an [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html) like extraction facility. Perhaps that is some of the source of the distinction?

*Edit 2* more details in: http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/localizing